# How to select child div using this property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here my code is:

```
<div class="FHD">   
    <div class="FHFD">    
        <div class="FHD">
           <div class="FHVD">AA</div>
           <div class="FHFD">AB</div>   
        </div>   
    </div>   
    <div class="FHVD">B</div>  
</div>
```

I have a div FHD which is of some height x,FHFD is height y.
Now i want to apply height to FHVD as x-y using js, so that when even the FHD height       changes only FHVD height should change and FHFD does not change its height.

I want to generalize the code as

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

   $('.FHC').each(function(){
       //here i want to get the height of FHFD div using 
       //$(this +' .FHFD").height()
       //somthing like this

   });
}
```

Thank in advance...

Comment: surely you mean `$(window).on('resize', function...)`.  also, avoid building css selectors from strings if you can—this is one good reason why  :)

Comment: Where's `$('.FHC')` ? or is that a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
window.onresize = function(event) {

    $('.FHC').each(function(){
        var heightFHFD = $(this).find('.FHFD').height()
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.FHC').each(function(){
     console.log(  $(this).height());
 });
```

Comment: i want to get the height of $('. FHFD') div?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) method:

```
$('.FHC').each(function(){ 
   var height = $(this).children('.FHFD').height();
   console.log(height);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        window.onresize = function(event) {

           $('.FHD').each(function(){
               $(this).find('.FHVD').height( $(this).height);

           });
        }
```